# Почему не генерируется исключение

Tags: c#

Есть два кода

Код 1

```
static void Main()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew((o) => { int x = 5 /(int) o; }, 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Код 2

```
class a
{
    public void Foo(object x)
    {
        int y = 5 /(int) x;
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(A.Foo);
        t.Start(0);
    }
}
```

Как видно из них, то в обоих случаях происходит попытка деления на нуль, однако почему в `КОДЕ 1` не происходит выбрасывания эксепшина, а в `Коде 2` происходит ? Ведь что первый, что второй метод запускаются в разных потоках. Объясните пожалуйста

Add:

Если добавить такую строчку в Коде 1 вместо `Thread.Sleep()` -         `Task.WaitAll(t);` тогда эксепш выстреливает. Но почему ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Второй код использует class `Thread`, первый код использует class `Task` для запуска кода в другом потоке.

При появлении исключения, поведение по умолчанию для `Thread`-а - завершить программу, поведение по умолчанию для `Task` - перехватить исключение и сохранить его в `Task`.

Если исключение возникло при выполнении `Task`, то `await`, `t.Wait` и `Task.WaitAll` распаковывают исключение из `Task` и кидают его в текущем потоке.